# How to read values from PBI Slicer and use in Rscript(Data source) of PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, rscript, powerbi-datasource

Is it possible to read selected value of PBI Slicer from PowerBI and use it in R script(Datasource) to retrieve the results, which generates new datasource.

The thing is column filter works great on data frame generated with R script but what I need is to do calculation based on the selected value of specific column rather then just filtering data.

To simplify , I will put it this way, is it possible to create dynamic Rscript rather than static ones in PowerBI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to Read value of PBI Slicer/ Filter and recalculate the Data and  Generate Graph accordingly, R Script Visual is the answer.

- Create R script using loaded columns and filters,
- Make sure this generates visual, else ERROR.
- During calculation Generated DF are not loaded in Datasource But can be used to Refresh the Graph.
- The visual, reads data from filter, runs script generates DF and hence Dynamic graphs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will probably make more progress by doing as much of the data transformation as possible in the Query Editor UI.

Your requirement sounds like "Add a Custom Column" or "Add a Conditional Column", where you can derive a new column based on values in other columns.

Comment: No, actually based on the user's input (selection) I want to pass this value to the Rscript and Refresh my Dataframe(Datasource table).

Comment: So, what are they selecting? A PBI Slicer?

Comment: exactly what I meant by filter was actually PBI slicer. Is there a way to detect which value is selected and to use it in Rscript? Thnx

Comment: All the datasource calculations happen during the dataset Refresh, not dynamically in response to Slicers and other filters.  Perhaps you can achieve what you want by adding the column referenced in the slicer to the Query (e.g. via Merge) before your R script?

Comment: Thanks @Mike Honey I will try and keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

**Background:**
I know this is an older post, but I believe that I figured this out based on my own project need, and it works fine in a small example. I can say though that when I transitioned it to a large dataset, it is VERY slow to the point where I probably won't use it; however, I figured maybe I should share the findings. *My goal* was to create a stacked column chart via ggplot2::geom_col through the "R script visual". I then wanted to have the ability to change how the data is filled (color coded) based on the user selection in a slicer.

**Answer:**
To do this, I have the following example tables:

1. Fake data (x,y) with two different variables it could be color coded by ("Filter_Foo", "Filter_Bar").
2. A static table containing the field names by which I want to filter the R graphic (i.e. "Filter_Foo", "Filter_Bar")

[image]

I then had the following visuals on the report. Notably, a slicer was made using the "Fill_To_R" table, with the idea that a user selects what value to pass into the R script.
[image]

Then create a measure defined as the value selected in the slicer, and this is what gets passed into the R script. I added a "card" to the report at the far-right which is simply displaying the measure (i.e. the selected value).
[image]

Then you create the R visual bringing in the data you want to plot (X,Y) as well as the parameters I wanted to color code by ("Filter_Foo", "Filter_Bar"), but then most importantly the defined measure ("Selection").

[image]

The R script I used to generate the graphic is here. Note that I had to reference the the first record of "dataset$Selection[1]" - without the index number, it does not work.

```
require("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
    {if(dataset$Selection[1]=="Filter_Foo"){geom_col(data = dataset, aes(y = Y, x = X, fill=Filter_Foo), width=0.8)}} +
    {if(dataset$Selection[1]=="Filter_Bar"){geom_col(data = dataset, aes(y = Y, x = X, fill=Filter_Bar), width=0.8)}} +
    xlab("X Category") +
    ylab("Total Y") + 
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,10), ylim=c(0,25)) +
    annotate(geom="text", label = paste0("Selection: ", dataset$Selection[1]), x=1, y=25, vjust=1, hjust=1, size= 3, col="black")
```

So now, based on if the user selected "Filter_Bar" or "FilterFoo", the R visual is taking that value and adjusting the plot accordingly. You can either exand upon this example directly, or just use it as reference for reading a measure into R to do with it what you will.
[image]